# Saving data to local memory restriction windows 8 metro style apps

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, memory-limit

I was wondering if there are memory limits for metro style apps. I am not talking about the RAM. That I already found out has a limit of 150 mb, right?

I want to know, if there is a restriction of using the local memory (the hard discstorage). I am creating a database to save alot of data. Can i do so until the device runs out of storage? (I am not actually planning to do so. But occupying like 80mb of the memory would be nice)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit on local data.

*Local application data should be used for any information that needs to be preserved between application sessions and is not suitable type or size wise, for roaming application data. Data that is not applicable on other devices should be stored here as well. There are no general size restriction on local data stored. Location is available via the localFolder property. Use the local app data store for data that it does not make sense to roam and for large data sets.*

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx).  There is a limit on roaming data.  Same document has that.