# Large file storage for metro apps

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, isolatedstorage

I need to ***download and store large files*** (mostly videos) in a win8 metro app. *What's the best recommended way?* IsolatedStorage? *What is the size limit for it?** I tried googling, but I'm yet to come up with anything definite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving data to local memory restriction windows 8 metro style apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508015/saving-data-to-local-memory-restriction-windows-8-metro-style-apps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any size limits on the [ApplicationData.LocalFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx), I certainly wouldn't recommend the [ApplicationData.RoamingFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingfolder.aspx).

Another possibility is the [KnownFolders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.aspx), for your case the Videos library seems like a nice solution.

For the known folders you need to declare in your app manifest that your app wants to access them.

Comment: Files copied to LocalFolder will only be available to my app, while files in KnownFolders will be accessible to everyone, right?

Comment: TDaver: not necessarily other users, but other applications with the same user, yes.  The KnownFolders is equivalent to the classic windows "My Documents/My Pictures/etc" folders.